# Use the contents of a file to rename it

Tags: string, file, batch-file, vbscript

I have binary datafiles that are approximately 20 MB in size and that have random filenames, all starting with "AA".  In each file's content, they have a specific string at a fixed position (in all files starting at 2086'th byte). I want to read that string consisting of 2 words (with 1 space in between like "MyName Sirname" in the example below) and use it along with the file creation date to rename the file.

Here is a shortened example file (first 3Kb):
`dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18286876/short.zhr`

We want to rename this specific file to "MyName Sirname YYYY-MM-DD".

It would be best if the script iterates through all files starting with "AA" in the currant directory. The script could be vbs or batch+vbs combination whatever is simplier.

This may seem a duplicate but the original question lacked detail, was wrongly focused on batch and the given answer was not sufficient.

Comment: I am unable to access the file at `dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18286876/short.zhr`.

Comment: Do you want some one to create this script for you?

Comment: Note that the "funny character" in `"MyName Sirname YYYY-MM-DD"` is actually the length byte indicating the length of "Sirname" (ASCII 7). My answer shows how to 'get it right' using the length bytes. /cc @STLDeveloper

Comment: @virusrocks - It would be most cordially welcome! I'm MD and the only language I used to know a little was php. I made a daring attempt to solve it by myself but it was a waste of time. 
And yes it's an extended duplicate (@Endoro) but in a previous post I got only a hint that it can't be done with batch file only. So one again I ask for help.

Comment: you may read this files with a command line hex dumper eg. `xxd` and grab the desired date info with `sed`. this maybe can go.

Comment: @not-sehe -that is right, there is also a lenght bite before myname -value 6 in the example and 1 before M that stands for male sex. But is it usefull for the extraction?

Comment: @MrGray My answer uses them both. I'd say it's useful :)

Comment: Some random thoughts: **a.** consider your legal obligations to leave the filenames privacy-neutral **b.** consider creating hard-links or sym-links instead of renaming the original. Just my $0.02

Comment: The files come from 2 sources local machine and the filename has as "lastname firstname date" structure and from remote and the name is "AA" plus random string. After downlowning the files from remote into local I want them to have meningful uniform names. As mentioned - since the file header is not encripted the legal issue is not an issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work, assuming that all of your files are in the same folder `C:\some\where`:

```
Const offset = 2085

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\some\where").Files
  If Left(f.Name, 2) = "AA" Then
    Set stream = f.OpenAsTextStream
    stream.Skip(offset)

    words = Array()
    Do
      length = Asc(stream.Read(1))
      If length <> 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve words(UBound(words)+1)
        words(UBound(words)) = stream.Read(length)
      End If
    Loop Until length = 0 Or stream.AtEndOfStream

    stream.Close

    If UBound(words) >= 1 Then
      fdate = Year(f.DateCreated) & "-" & Right("0" & Month(f.DateCreated), 2) _
        & "-" & Right("0" & Day(f.DateCreated), 2)
      f.Name = words(0) & " " & words(1) & " " & fdate _
        & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)
    End If
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Outputs error: line 21, char 5, Index out of range:'[number: 1]', code 800A0009

Comment: The processed file seems to have had only a single word at the given offset (unlike your sample file, which had 4).

Comment: i used the same file that was posted

Comment: The offset must be 2085, not 2086. Fixed.

Comment: `f.OpenAsTextStream` - I stopped reading right there

Comment: OMG! it works! I cant belive! I'm saved. After 2 weeks of hopeless trials and errors, attempts and failures I'm home. I would be there without you people. THANKS! And special thanks @AnsgarWiechers!

Comment: OK there is a small problem after I run it on a real folder (no worries -had a backup). The date for the filename is date of birth taken from the header and it should be date-created file property (prefared). If it's a difficulty the header also has a useful field - date recorded - it is second date few "fields" down the string. This is needed in case of repeated recordings. Btw - how does the script react in case of existing filename conflict? Autooverwrite is not an option.

Comment: Updated answer to get the date from the file's creation date. As for name conflicts: in its current form the script will raise an error when a file with the same name already exists. This issue could be dealt with by appending a running number.

Comment: Now it works exactly as intended -thanks again, now I can focus on actually reading ecg and not looking for it!

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** The file appears to be in "Composite Document File V2 Document" format. There are likely libraries that can read this the appropriate way.
>
> Wild guess: Are you trying to "read" Outlook `.msg` files, word/excel documents?
>
> Use `file` or see
>
> - http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/13/how-do-i-get-document-information-from-the-command/

---

### **UPDATE** C++ version added (*see below*)

A little hacking with the file told me it's a binary file and the strings are not delimited, but preceded by their length bytes. So, this bash script should work in general:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e # stop on errors

for originalname in "$@"
do
    # get lengths
    first_len=$(od -j 2085 "$originalname" -An -t u1 -N1)
    second_len=$(od -j $((2086 + $first_len)) "$originalname" -An -t u1 -N1)

    # strip whitespace
    read first_len second_len <<< "$first_len $second_len"

    # extract the words as text
    firstword=$(dd if="$originalname" bs=1 skip=2086 count=$first_len)
    secondword=$(dd if="$originalname" bs=1 skip=$((2087+$first_len)) count=$second_len)

    # calculate new name, using the timestamp of the file too:
    newname="$firstword $secondword $(date -r "$originalname" +"%Y-%m-%d")"

    # do the move (verbosely)
    mv -v "$originalname" "$(dirname "$originalname")/$newname"
done
```

I tested it on the file you supplied:

> `$ ./test.sh short.zhr 2>/dev/null`
>
> ```
>    `short.zhr' -> `./MyName Sirname 2013-06-11'
> ```

You gotta love UNIX philosophy :)

For your case you could just run

```
 ./test.sh somedir/AA*
```

### C++ version

For fun I wrote a C++ version. This should be pretty easily portable.

It's actually a bit more readable (except for the part to formats the timestamp...).

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <iostream>

std::string extract_string(std::istream& is) {
    char len;
    if (is && is.read(&len, 1)) {
        std::string result(len, '\0');
        is.read(&*result.begin(), len);
        return result;
    }
    return "";
}

std::string timestamp(std::string const& fname, const char* fmt = "%Y-%m-%d")
{
    struct stat sb;
    if (-1 == stat(fname.c_str(), &sb))
        perror("cannot get file stats");

    if (struct tm* tmp = localtime(&sb.st_ctime))
    {
        std::string buf(200, '\0');
        buf.resize(strftime(&*buf.begin(), buf.size(), fmt, tmp));
        return buf;
    } else
        perror("localtime failed");
    return "";
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i<argc; ++i)
    {
        const std::string fname(argv[i]);
        std::ifstream stream(fname.c_str(), std::ios::binary);

        stream.seekg(2085);
        std::string first  = extract_string(stream);
        std::string second = extract_string(stream);

        std::string newname = first + " " + second + " " + timestamp(fname);
        std::cout << (("rename \"" + fname + "\" \""  + newname + "\"").c_str());
    }
}
```

<strike>You'd use it in exactly the same way. Of course, you could make this *print* the `newname` instead, and use it from your own script(s).</strike> **Edit** Edited the version to cross compile to win-exe. Made it print a `rename` command.

Comment: This is medical file - 24 hours of ECG (ie HOLTER ECG). The filename is random for "security" but it's unpractical for storing/searching and the header is not even encripted as you see. Thanks for the imput, I'll try that at home but here it needs to run on Windows.

Comment: I made this on windows. I'm at work, and use http://www.cygwin.com/ bash, though other windows ports of bash/od/date/dd should suffice.

Comment: @Sehe would have explained this better

Comment: @MrGray added a c++ version. This should be trivially compiled to a windows executable.

Comment: @MrGray In case you trust a "random executable from the web" you might try **[rename-holter-ecg.exe](http://downloads.sehe.nl/stackoverflow/rename-holter-ecg.exe)** which I cross-compiled using `mingw32` on my home linux box. (It works under http://www.winehq.org/)

Comment: @thecoshman Do you reckon a [C++ reimplementation](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17042442/4) counts as explanation?

Comment: i think i downloaded some lousy compiler, namely Turbo C++ 3.0 freeware, it outputs include error 3x

Comment: Haha. Try [VS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) (heavy, with IDE) or [MingW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/). Or, you know, test my cross-compiled download :)

Comment: thanks for the rename-holter-ecg.exe - i gave it a try
some debbuging output or log might be useful - blank screen and no change

Comment: @MrGray Not to be too obvious, but how did you use it? Intended use: `rename-holter-ecg.exe short.zhr` e.g.

Comment: By the way, could the downvoter _please_ comment?

Comment: -1 for proposing bash and C++ when the OP explicitly requested batch and/or VBScript.

Comment: rename-holter-ecg.exe works with a parameter - outputs what it was supposed to output, but than it needs to make a loop in batch to make it a working solution. Thanks for this input as well but I'll stick to vbs.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers fair enough, thanks for explaining