# Use the contents of a file to rename alternate companion files

Tags: string, batch-file, rename

I have read some topics ( [Use the contents of a file to rename it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041863/use-the-contents-of-a-file-to-rename-it) ) and while they touch upon my problem I do not have the depth to modify them to my needs. I would prefer a batch solution althou other would be fine.

I have a few hundred files in the order of :-

- PHRASE0001.J8I
- PHRASE0001.WAV
- PHRASE0002.J8I
- PHRASE0002.WAV

Every J8I binary file begins :-

```
JS-8  ¬¬fmt    ¬   ¬J8I   ¬    ¬Pop:Classic Pop
JS-8  ¬¬fmt    ¬   ¬J8I   ¬    ¬Pop:Classic Pop (Simple)
```

Every J8I Binary file is then padded with 00 hex for approx 256bytes before 1kb of data and then EOF.

I would like a batch to take the string "Pop:Classic Pop" offset at 33btyes in PHRASE0001.J8I and rename its sister file PHRASE0001.WAV to "Pop - Classic Pop.WAV" (ie removing all colons, some files have two and replacing it with " - " (SPACEDASHSPACE)

Only WAV's are to be renamed depending on what's in the corresponding J8I file.

Hence PHRASE0002.WAV should be renamed "Pop - Classic Pop (Simple).WAV" or a file named PHRASE0245.WAV should be renamed "Latin - Samba1 (BPM - 100).WAV" when PHRASE0245.J8I contains

```
JS-8  ¬¬fmt    ¬   ¬J8I   ¬    ¬Latin:Samba1 (BPM:100)
```

I beleieve this script can be used in many circumstances and once completed could be easily modifyed even by me.

Thanks for looking

Charlie

I forgot, I can't be sure because I have not checked every file but I think the longest string is something like "Country: Country Ballad (Alternative)" or not very much longer but they are always followed by 00's, I guess either truncating from 64 characters should be enough to avoid errors or reading until hitting multiple spaces should be enough to find the string legnth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the example files, which have nulls throughout, this is tested and it works here.

Test it for yourself on some sample files in a folder - you will need to download the free `GNUsed` for Windows
and probably also need to replace `sed` in the script with your install location,
like `"c:\utils\gnused\sed.exe"` unless you put it (and the sed support files) in a folder on the PATH.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.J8I) do (
   if exist "%%~na.wav" for /f "delims=" %%b in (' sed -e "s/^.\{32\}\(.[^\x00]*\).*/\1/" -e "s/:/ - /g" "%%a" ') do (
      if exist "%%~na.wav" echo renaming "%%~na.wav" to "%%b.wav" & ren "%%~na.wav" "%%b.wav"
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: See my edited code - it uses a different helper tool called `GnuSed` which needs to be installed.  The NULLS are difficult to deal with in batch scripts.

Comment: Yeah that worked a treat, Thanks :) ... It's not the first time I've been stuck to rename files and I'm sure it wont be the last, this will save me editing 911 files and then renameing 911 files and I can also put it to future use too. Thank you, thank you, thank you, your just awsome! For anyone else reading, I extracted sed binary and dependcies to same folder as that batch and target files and did not modify the code. I deletes my replies to make the topic cleaner and easier to follow. Take Care Foxidrive :)

Comment: Thanks, without the `g` command it would have not been able to rename some of the files because the `:` characters would give an error.  I've added a line to the code to echo the lines into a log file as they are renaming.  You can examine the log file afterward to see which files failed and possibly see the reason.

Comment: Yes, I think I've gotten around that issue in the edited code above.  All's well, I'm glad it got the job done.

Comment: slight edit, you missed a qutation mark before & ren `echo renaming "%%~na.wav" to "%%b.wav" & ren "%%~na.wav" "%%b.wav"` .I found an edit button and tried myself out of curosity but wasnt aproved. Thank you again, perfect!!!

Comment: You did the right thing.  Ta.  I've added it - the people who rejected it weren't really on the ball. :)