# Move file to archive if header contains a specific string using vbs

Tags: file, vbscript

I have a problem processing Holter ECG (medical) files based on headers within. Those are  binary datafiles that are approximately 20 MB in size starting with structured header and than the data. What I would like to achive is preferably with vbs script is:

1) To check all files in the current folder and move the processed ones to the archive folder -based on specific string in the header:
After a constant string "User Field #20" comes a 250-400 chars long text string that contains a substring like "Wn:" or "WN:" or "wn:" (with colon). If its there the file is processed and goes to archive.
The two examples hold conclusion strings like:

i)

> Analize przeprowadzono w warunkach szpitalnych. Rytm prowadzacy zatokowy z HR sr 70/min ( zakres 45-133/min).
>   Zarejestrowano 1 SVPB, bez epizodow czestoskurczu. Komorowych zaburzeń rytmu serca nie ma.
>   PQ i QTc w normie.
>   WN: zapis prawidłowy bez zaburezń rytmu serca

ii)

> Zapis w warunkach szpitalnych. Rytm zatokowy, HR w zakresie 38 /min do 126/min, średnio 66/min; przeciętnie w dzień 58-95/min, w nocy 52-65/min. Nie zarejestrowano SVPB, VPB, pauz>2,5sek.PQ w normie wiekowej. QTc prawidłowe. Dobowy profil rytmu w normie.
>   Wn: Zapis holterowski bez cech istotnej patologii

Newlines, special and regional chars possible within the string. I cant tell for sure but seems like the conclusions string ends with hex 80 (euro sign).

2) If possible - add log to the script - plain text, semicolon separated (maybe to be uploaded to excel if necessary).
   archive_log.txt: Timestamp; Lastname; Firstname; DateRecorded; DateProcessed; ConclusionsLongText (about 250-400 chars).
DateRecorded and DateProcessed based on files date created and last modified.

This is extension of a problem that was solved some time ago. The problem is different, only the files to handle are the same. [Use the contents of a file to rename it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041863/use-the-contents-of-a-file-to-rename-it)

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: with checking if the string is present within the header. If it helps I uploaded two example files after anonimization and cutting them short after the header end. https://www.dropbox.com/s/32mnh4l8i9imoyx/short_with_descr1.zhr  https://www.dropbox.com/s/xcxm2l2pjhuxpqq/short_with_descr2.zhr

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same strategy Ansgar used in the link you referenced. Read the file contents and then you can use `InStr()` to search for your string:

```
    ' Read the entire file into a string...
    strContents = objFS.OpenTextFile("file.dat").ReadAll()

    ' Search for the string "WN:" (case-insensitive)...
    intPos = InStr(1, strContents, "WN:", vbTextCompare)

    If intPos > 0 Then
        ' Found
    End If
```

This should find the first `"WN:"` occurrence within the file. Note that this could be some other occurrence, outside the header, so you could also determine the position of `"User Field"` and compare that to the position of `"WN:"`. For example:

```
    intPosUser = InStr(1, strContents, "User Field", vbTextCompare)
    intPosWN   = InStr(1, strContents, "WN:", vbTextCompare)

    ' "WN:" should be within 400 chars of the first User Field record...
    If intPosWN > intPosUser And intPosWN - intPosUser < 400 Then
        ' Found
    End If
```